# Laravel Vapor error: "You have reached your network limit for this region."

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

After connecting my Vapor account to AWS via the IAM role, when I try to create a new Vapor project using the Web UI, I get the following error: [image: You have reached your network limit for this region.]

I have no idea if this is purely a Vapor problem or something I need to fix over at AWS since I don't really know about any limits on AWS. BTW I do have other Vapor projects using other AWS accounts on this Vapor account.

Comment: I did never use Vapor, but based on the message, I am assuming it is an AWS "error", you may have reached a VPC limit on that user/region: https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/projects/the-basics.html#creating-projects (check the violet tip, that is related to VPCs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS has a VPC limit which is a maximum of 5 VPCs per region by default. AWS does allow us to request an increase in the limit.

I had already hit the limit before trying to create a new Vapor project since Vapor does create a VPC for itself. So I deleted the other VPCs that I wasn't using (except the default VPC) and Vapor worked.